# Python Stanza: Some Tokens don't have a lemma?

Tags: python, nlp, stanza

I noticed that the token "sep" when using stanza pipeline ("en") does not have a lemma attribute...
[image]

```
import stanza 
nlp_tokenize = stanza.Pipeline('en', processors='tokenize,mwt,pos,lemma,depparse', \
   tokenize_pretokenized = True, use_gpu=True)#, use_gpu=False) 
doc = nlp_tokenize("sep") # the word "sep" has no attribute lemma 
print(doc)
```

This is the only token I've found, where this problem occured (all the other tokens do have the lemma attribute).

Why is that?

Comment: Please post the script as text not screenshot.

Comment: Not in comment. Edit your post

Comment: It seems that you should address not token, but its word subclass. Check in the documentation, [here](https://stanfordnlp.github.io/stanza/data_objects.html#token).